# close RethinkDB changefeed before changed

Tags: node.js, sockets, rethinkdb

I can't seem to find any info in the rethinkdb docs on how you might stop a changefeed before the first change is fired. Here's the problem that makes this necessary:

A client connects to the server via a socket, which begins a changefeed, something like this:

```
var changeCursors = {};
db('app').table('things').changes().run(cursor, function(err, cursor) {
  // do something when changed
  changeCursors[user.id] = cursor
})

// later, when the user disconnects
changeCursors[user.id].close()
```

When the first change is dispatched, I can assign the cursor to a variable in memory, and if the client disconnects, close this cursor.

However, what if the user disconnects before the first change?

As far as I can tell, rethink doesn't support dispatching an initial state to the feed, so the cursor will only be available after a change. However, if the user disconnects, `changeCursors[user.id]` is undefined, and the changefeed stays open forever.

This can be solved by checking a state object inside the changefeed and just closing the feed after the first change, but in theory if there are no changes and many connected clients, we can potentially open many cursors that will eat memory for no reason (they'll be closed as soon as they update).

Is there a way to get the cursor from a changefeed without the `run` callback being executed? Alternatively, is there a way to force rethink to perform an initial state update to the `run` callback?

Comment: Thank you for this question -- I was just googling for how to close an change cursor, and your code showed me that --  I'm curious, because I didn't find it in the docs, where did you find cursor.close() ??  
Also - the idea of maintaining the array of cursors per user/connection is excellent and I've used a variation of it now too.  Thanks again.

Comment: There it is: https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#close-cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have this problem even if the server responded immediately, because the user might disconnect after you've sent the query to the server and before the response has made it back.  Unfortunately we can't create the cursor before sending the query to the server because in the general case figuring out the return type of the query is sort of hard, so we don't put that logic in the clients.

I think the best option is what you described, where if the cursor hasn't been returned yet you set a flag and close it inside the callback.  You might be able to make the logic cleaner using promises.

I wouldn't worry about memory usage unless you're sure it's a problem; if some portion of a second passes without a change, we return a cursor with no initial values to the client, so your memory use in the case of a lot of users opening and then immediately closing connections will be proportional to how many users can do that in that portion of a second.  If that portion of a second is too long for you, you can configure it to be smaller with the optargs to `run` (http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/run/).  (I would just set `firstBatchScaledownFactor` to be higher in your case.)

Comment: Ah, I see - I'll continue with my current solution, thanks for the informed answer about memory usage, I'll assume holding those open will be ok for now, and revisit if I run in to issues!